# Unable to cat Ruby blocks to files

Tags: ruby, bash, heredoc

Please help, I am stuck here ---

```
irb> a = "line of text\n  line two\n  line three"
irb> system("cat > test_file << #{a}")
cat: of: No such file or directory
cat: text: No such file or directory
=> false
```

Comment: Exactly! Because this looks like a very unpretty thing. What do you really want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the interpolated parameter:

```
system("cat > test_file << \"#{a}\"")
```

And, cat is expecting a filename, not some text to append to test_file, so, this would work as I think you intended:

```
system("echo \"#{a}\" >> test_file")
```

If you want to do this in pure Ruby let me know and I'll give you an example.

Comment: `system("cat > test_file << \"#{a}\"")' produces an empty file, `system("echo \"#{a}\" >> testfile")' produces a solution, but your communication of the idea is hard to understand of itself.

Answer (score 3):

Write a to a file called "testfile":

```
File.open("testfile", "w") do |io| io.print a done
```

Comment: File.open("testfile", "w") do |f| f << "formatted text block" end  ..... works.  thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a file directly has already been covered by JesperE.  To write to a process (in this case a "cat" process) use popen.

```
IO.popen("cat > foo", "w") do
    |f|
    f.write("line1\nline2\n")
end
```

Comment: really?  who else has covered it?

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but that's like a car mechanic asking "what's an engine?"